# How to center background image in VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

I am trying to center my background image and prevent the image from being repeated in Visual Force and in Visual Flows,
This is the command line I am using:

```
<body style=" background-image:url('{!$Resource.bkgrdimage}');" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-attachment="fixed" background-position="center"></body>
```

But the image is not centered and is repeated on the right edge,

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect. In fact, you close out your style tag right away and then have non-supported attributes on the body. You don't use that syntax of:

```
property="value"
```

The correct syntax for CSS is:

```
property: value;
```

Try this:

```
<body style="background-image:url('{!$Resource.bkgrdimage}');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;background-position:center;"></body>
```

Notice how all of your styles are now part of a single `style=""`. As a side note, the proper way to do this would be to have a CSS file you include that applies these styles. That file would look like:

```
body{
    background-image:url('{!$Resource.bkgrdimage}');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This needs a pure css approach.

Also to make actually work you need to change your visualforce page version to `28.0` as summer '14 provided a feature of implementing our own `html` tag and `body` tag.

First set your `apex:page` as:

`<apex:page showHeader="false" applybodyTag="false" controller="MyController">`

and then use `body` tag

```
<body class="bckground">
</body>
```

css

```
.bckground
{
  background: url("{!$Resource.myBackgroundImage}") no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: You can apply the CSS directly to the body element. You don't need to add a class to it, but it doesn't really matter to be honest.

Comment: @JesseAltman Yep! :) Just a choice!

Comment: @regal I did as you suggested. Still not working...Here's my  declaration <apex:page controller="dataTableCon" id="thePage" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false">